# SQL select column if attribute is true

Tags: sql

I'm overthinking a lot about this, but what I'm trying to do is to select only the columns that is true from `object.attribute`.

Scenario: I have one function java, inside of this function I have an `object` that has 50 `attribute` that has true or false. I'm trying to create a dynamic query that select only the columns if `object.attribute` is `true`. For example, `Person` is my object and has 50 attribute, `name, age, sex, wage` and so on. If `Person.name` is `true`, `Person.sex` is `true`, `Person.wage` is `false`, `Person.age` is `false`, select the `name` and `sex` column only.

I tried to use `String sql = "...IF ELSE ..."` or `String sql = "...CASE WHEN..."` but I couldn't create the logic where the `true` come in, if do `column_name = object.attribute(true)`, will return null. Is it better to create a procedure? Or it can done in a query? How can I achieve this?

If only shows name and sex, must appear "John", "31" as example

Comment: You want to select a column based on it's value?

Comment: Also, is it too much overhead to pull back all data and then filter on the application side? Because if that is ok, then I would definitely take that approach as you could have consistent behavior without all the junky SQL.

Comment: I could go only for `true` attributes, instead of both.

Comment: You would have to either do this using dynamic sql or build up a string as pass through sql from the front end. Why would some instances of a Person have an age property and others don't? Seems you are not providing the whole story of what you are really trying to do here.

Comment: If a person want to see some information, he can select what data he wants to see. Like age, name, sex ... What he chooses, only the `true` will show for him.

Comment: How much data total could they pull back realistically? Rows and columns. If it's not a data size concern, I would filter it out in code. I think that will be a better solution that writing a ton of dynamic SQL

Comment: Basically have milions of rows and 27 columns.

Comment: So the are pulling back a million rows? Really? If it's 1000 or less, I still think your best option is not loading columns in code even though data came back. Otherwise, see my answer

Comment: NO! I mean I have milions of rows. But it only pull One. I understand in a another way what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to craft dynamic SQL and use parameters to properly do this. So you would be building a SQL string for the SELECT, but any non-static parameters needed for the query would be parameters. to the query itself.

So, you would have something in code like:

```
String Sql = ""
Sql=sql + " SELECT "
IF attribute.value==true then Sql=sql + value.name + " "
IF attribute.value==true then Sql=sql + value.name + " "
IF attribute.value==true then Sql=sql + value.name + " "
Sql=sql + "FROM TABLE WHERE StaticField=StaticValue or StaticField=@Var1"
```

You never should concatenate user input; that is where the parameters (@Var1 in the example above) come into play.